# When macro tries to modify a chart in a protected sheet (UserInterfaceOnly) -> Error#:1004

Tags: vba, excel

Sheet1 is protected from `Workbook_Open()` using:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="Pass1", UserInterfaceOnly:=True.
```

A macro is trying to change the font size of Chart1's Axes label, using the following statement:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart1").Chart. _ 
             Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Size = 10
```

and I get the following error:

> **Error: 1004.**
>
> Unable to set the Size property of the font class.

When I use the following workaround, the problem does not occur anymore:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Unprotect "Pass1"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart1").Chart. _
             Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Size = 10
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect "Pass1"
```

But I want to avoid using Unprotect/Protect sheet that's why I choose to use

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet").Protect Password:="Pass1", _
         UserInterfaceOnly:=True,
```

which seems not to work for the particular case.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what it is you want. To modify a protected sheet you need to unprotect it first. That's the whole point of protecting. What is your desired behavior?

Comment: @AlexisOlson His sheet is protected in user interface only. Which means VBA should be able to modify without a problem even if it is protected.

Comment: @litelite Thank you. That makes sense. @Anastasios it looks like you are protecting `Worksheets("Sheet")` and then trying to modify `Worksheets("Sheet1")`. Shouldn't the sheet names match?

Comment: @AlexisOlson. Hi, actually this is a typo in the post, I protect Worksheets("Sheet1") and still does not work. I'll update the question to correct the typo.

Comment: Have you check is there is any other procedure protecting the `Sheet1` after the workbook is opened. Notice that you are not always protecting `Sheet1` with UserInterfaceOnly:=True. You could also try to trigger the protection using the `Worksheet_Activate` event.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`Worksheet.Protect` has a variety of arguments you can use (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840611.aspx)). In particular, try adding the `DrawingObjects:=False` argument to your protecting code

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="Pass1", _ 
             UserInterfaceOnly:=True, DrawingObjects:=False
```

which will explicitly allow you to modify the charts.

It appears that `UserInterfaceOnly:=True` doesn't truly give VBA full permission as mentioned [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/343337-userinterfaceonly-%3Dtrue-problem.html).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your prompt answer. If I use `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Protect Password:="Pass1", _ 
             UserInterfaceOnly:=True, DrawingObjects:=False`, it means that the DrawingObjects will not be protected and a user will actually be able to modify them manually, right? So the best way to have the DrawingObjects protected and be able to change them with a macro is to Uprotect/Protect tem within the macro, right?

Comment: Probably the best thing to do is just have your macro unprotect everything at the beginning of the code and the protect it all again at the end of the code to avoid this sort of thing.